# Hide div and show another and change link class Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'v been researching most of today but not found much so I was wondering if you guys could help.

I have two links which I want to control two divs with. I want it so that when a link is clicked it shows the respective div and activates the class 'link-active' on that link. When the other link is clicked I want the old div to fade out and the new one relating to the new link to fade in and re-apply the 'link-active' class.

HTML:

```
<a href="#walking" id="walking" class="link-active"><p>Dog Walking</p></a>
<a href="#grooming" id="grooming"><p>Dog Grooming</p></a>

<div class="walk"></div>
<div class="groom"></div>
```

I understand this propably isnt the best description so here is a fiddle to help me out.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swift29/LUkk4/1/

Cheers in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses a simple function to handle the fadeIn/fadeOut.  It tries to eliminate code duplication as best as possible.

**Javascript**

```
$("#walking").click(function(){
    swap(this, "walk", "groom");
});

$("#grooming").click(function(){
  swap(this, "groom", "walk");
});

function swap(obj, active, inactive){
  $("." + inactive).fadeOut(500, function(){
      $("." + active).fadeIn().addClass("link-active");
  });
  $("#walking, #grooming").removeClass("link-active");
  $(obj).addClass("link-active");
}
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/LUkk4/6/

Comment: @swift29 glad I could help, I did update the solution so the link-active class would not be removed from items other than #walking and #grooming

Answer (score 0):

in your document ready event, add the following code to achieve the described behavior

```
$('#walking').click(function()
{
   $('.groom').fadeOut(100, function() 
   {
        $('.groom').removeClass('link-active');
        $('.walk').fadeIn(100, function()
        {   
            $('.walk').addClass('link-active');
        });
   });
   //prevent default click event
   return false;
});
```

add the same event to the other div, just replace the .walk and .groom classnames.